# Find out which Network Interface is which via node or Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I use an electron app that needs to send its active IP address (in a LAN) to my server for ongoing communication. For that I use a brilliant script I found here which works great:

```
function getIPs() {
    let ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    console.log(ifaces);
    let ipAdresse = '';
    Object.keys(ifaces).forEach(function (ifname) {
        let alias = 0;
        ifaces[ifname].forEach(function (iface) {
            if ('IPv4' !== iface.family || iface.internal !== false) {
                return;
            }
            if (alias >= 1) {
                console.log(ifname + ':' + alias, iface.address);
            } else {
                console.log(ifname, iface.address);
                ipAdress = iface.address;
            }
            ++alias;
        });
    });
    return ipAdress;
}
```

The Problem I have is: if this Client is connected to more then one Network (sometimes the users connect to a WIFI as well to have internet), I cannot tell which one is my LAN and which belongs to the WIFI. As I have no Control over the used WIFI I cannot tell them apart by their IP-Range.

Is there a way to tell (in Node or Electron) if an Network Interface belongs to Cable or WIFI?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as network interface object doesn't provide any info regarding WIFI etc.